# XmlSerializer, XmlArray with dynamic content... how?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, xmlserializer

To start: This is also for REST deserialiaztion, so a custom XmlSerializer is out of the question.

I have a hjierarchy of classes that need to be serializable and deserializable from an "Envelope". It has an arrayelement named "Items" that can contain subclasses of the abstract "Item".

```
[XmlArray("Items")]
public Item [] Items { get; set; }
```

Now I need to add XmlArrayItem, but the number is not "fixed". We use so far reflection to find all subclasses with a KnownTypeProvider so it is easy to extend the assembly with new subtypes. I dont really want to hardcode all items here.

The class is defined accordingly:

```
[XmlRoot]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes")]
public class Envelope {
```

but it does not help.

Changing Items to:

```
[XmlArray("Items")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Item))]
public Item [] Items { get; set; }
```

results in:

> {"The type
>   xxx.Adjustment
>   was not expected. Use the XmlInclude
>   or SoapInclude attribute to specify
>   types that are not known statically."}

when tyrying to serialize.

Anyone an idea how I can use XmlInclude to point to a known type provider?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the DataContractSerializer, especially when you are using WCF and the REST kit?  [KnownTypes] only work for the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KnownTypesAttribute does not work for XmlSerializer. It's only used by a DataContractSerializer. I'm quite sure that you can exchange the serializer in WCF, because I have done that for the DataContractSerializer. But if that's not an option, you have to implement IXmlSerializable yourself and handle type lookup there.

Before disqualifying this solution: You just have to implement IXmlSerializable just for a special class which replaces Item[]. Everything else can be handled by the default serializer.

Comment: I would hate to do so.... lots of work. Any idea how I can create my own instance of XmlSerializer and then use THAT ONE in WCF? If that works... I can (as has been shown) configure it to work properly in the constructor. BUt I need to be able to put my own instance there, not the one created by default.

Comment: First of all: Implementing IXmlSerializable might be much less effort than you might think. But I would neet to see more code. To replace the XmlSerializer you probably have to implement some WCF behaviour. XmlSerializerOperationBehavior might be a starting point.

Comment: I will accept that as answer. I will see that i Look into that behavios and possibly write my own.

Answer (score 1):

According to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/83181d16-a048-44e5-b675-a0e8ef82f5b7/

you can use different *XmlSerializer* constructor:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base), new Type[] { typeof(Derived1), ..});
```

Instead of enumerating all derived classes in the base definition like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Derived1))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(Derived2))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedN))]
```

I think you should be able to use your *KnownTypeProvider* to fill the array in the *XmlSerializer*'s constructor.

Comment: Ncie try, but as I said: I can not genrate the serializer myself. THe deserialization also happens in WCF with the REST api. Unless you can also solve that part (how to make WCF use my own deserializer).... it wont work.

Comment: Sorry, I thought different constructor does not count as a custom serializer. I think you can serialize it using DynamicAttributes (http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/01/10/dynamic-attributes-in-c.aspx), but then the deserialization will be still a problem. What about implementing _IXmlSerializable_ interface?